Find matching rows in dataframes based on number of matching items
I have two topic models, topics1 and topics2. They were created from very similar but different datasets. As a result, the words representing each topic/cluster as well as the topic numbers will be different for each dataset. A toy example looks like:
import pandas as pd
topics1 = pd.DataFrame({'topic_num':[1,2,3],
                        'words':[['red','blue','green'],
                                 ['blue','sky','cloud'],
                                 ['eat','food','nomnom']]
                        })
topics2 = pd.DataFrame({'topic_num':[1,2,3],
                        'words':[['blue','sky','airplane'],
                                 ['blue','green','yellow'],
                                 ['mac','bit','byte']]
                        })

For each topic in topics1, I would like to find the topic in topics2 with the maximum number of matches. In the above example, in topics1 topic_num 1 would match topic_num 2 intopics2 and topic_num 2 in topics1 would match topic_num 1 in topics2. In both of these cases, 2 of the 3 words in each row match across dataframes.
Is there a way to find this using built-in pandas functions such as eq()? My solution just iterated across every word in topics1 and eery word in topics2.

You will have to compute all combinations in any case.
You could use sets and broadcast the comparisons:
# set the topic_num as index
# convert the Series of lists to Series of sets
s1 = topics1.set_index('topic_num')['words'].map(set)
s2 = topics2.set_index('topic_num')['words'].map(set)

# convert to numpy arrays
# broadcast the intersection of s1 and s2
# to form a square array, convert back to DataFrame
# get the length of the intersection
tmp = (pd.DataFrame(s1.to_numpy()[:, None]
                    &s2.to_numpy(),
                    index=s1.index, columns=s2.index
                   )
         .map(len) #.applymap(len)
       )

# get the col id with the max length per row
# mask if the length was 0
out = tmp.idxmax(axis=1).where(tmp.gt(0).any(axis=1))

Output:
topic_num
1    2.0
2    1.0
3    NaN
dtype: float64

Intermediate tmp:
topic_num  1  2  3
topic_num         
1          1  2  0
2          2  1  0
3          0  0  0

Note that this logic can be wrapped by cdist as rightly suggested by @Onyambu, however I would first convert to set to avoid doing it repeatedly in the cdist (which would be expensive). This should be done in a bit weird way by encapsulating the sets in list since cdist requires a 2D input:
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

dst = lambda x, y : len(x[0] & y[0])
val = cdist([[set(x)] for x in topics1['words']],
            [[set(x)] for x in topics2['words']], dst)

pos = val.argmax(1)
out = pd.DataFrame({'topic1': topics1['topic_num'],
                    'topic2': (topics2['topic_num']
                               .iloc[pos]
                               .where(val[topics1.index, pos]!=0)
                               .values
                              )})
#    topic1  topic2
# 0       1     2.0
# 1       2     1.0
# 2       3     NaN


I'm getting an error on this, AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

It'd be applymap in versions < 2.1.0 @Adam_G

Indeed, the name of the methods recently changed. Either update pandas or replace map(len) by applymap(len).

Thanks! I was using a Colab notebook for this, and that's annoying that they have an old version of pandas. Could you add a few comments to the code so I understand what it's doing?

@Adam_G sure, I added some comments

You could use cdist:
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
dst = lambda x, y : len(set(x) & set(y))  
val = cdist(topics1['words'].to_list(), topics2['words'].to_list(), dst)
val

array([[1., 2., 0.],
       [2., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])

Then to obtain the positions:
pos = pd.Series(val.argmax(0))
pos.mask(pd.Series(val[topics1.index, pos]).eq(0))
0    1.0
1    0.0
2    NaN


For Huge datasets, Use : MultiLabelBinarizer which efficiently converts variable-length word lists into binary vectors.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'topic_num': [1, 2, 3],
                        'words': [['red', 'blue', 'green'], ['blue', 'sky', 'cloud'], ['eat', 'food', 'nomnom']]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'topic_num': [1, 2, 3],
                        'words': [['blue', 'sky', 'airplane'], ['blue', 'green', 'yellow'], ['mac', 'bit', 'byte']]})


'''
df1 :
   topic_num                words
0          1   [red, blue, green]
1          2   [blue, sky, cloud]
2          3  [eat, food, nomnom]
df2 :
   topic_num                  words
0          1  [blue, sky, airplane]
1          2  [blue, green, yellow]
2          3       [mac, bit, byte]
'''


all_words = set(sum(df1['words'].tolist() + df2['words'].tolist(), [] ))

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes = list(all_words))

binarized_df1 = mlb.fit_transform(df1['words'])
binarized_df2 = mlb.fit_transform(df2['words'])
'''
binarized_df1 :
[[1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]]
binarized_df2 :
[[1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]
'''
# Convert to sparse matrices
sparse_df1 = csr_matrix(binarized_df1)
sparse_df2 = csr_matrix(binarized_df2)

# Compute the dot product to get the number of matches
match_matrix = sparse_df1.dot(sparse_df2.T).toarray()
'''
match_matrix :
[[1 2 0]
 [2 1 0]
 [0 0 0]]
'''
# Find the indices of the maximum matches
max_match_indices = np.argmax(match_matrix,axis=1)
max_match_values = np.max(match_matrix,axis=1)

df_res = pd.DataFrame(
{ 'df1_topic_num' : df1['topic_num'],
'df2_col_match' : np.where(max_match_values > 0, max_match_indices +1 ,np.nan)
}    
)
print(df_res)
'''
   df1_topic_num  df2_col_match
0              1            2.0
1              2            1.0
2              3            NaN
'''
# OR
df_res1 = pd.DataFrame({
'df1_topic_num' : df1['topic_num'],
'df2_col_match' : np.where(max_match_values > 0, df2['topic_num'].iloc[max_match_indices], np.nan )    
    
})
print(df_res1 )

'''
   df1_topic_num  df2_col_match
0              1            2.0
1              2            1.0
2              3            NaN
'''

